# How do I map Linux Kernels to Ubuntu Kernels?

Tags: kernel

## Ubuntu Kernels and Linux Kernels have different numbers

With the recent Meltdown and Spectre security holes I've been reading on new releases of the Linux Kernel. How do I translate the latest Linux Kernel version number, say `4.15.5` to corresponding Ubuntu Kernel version numbers?

Answer (score 5):

Go to this [page](https://people.canonical.com/~kernel/info/kernel-version-map.html) and search on `4.15.5` and you will see:

```
Ubuntu Kernel Version   Ubuntu Kernel Tag     Mainline Kernel Version
4.15.0-11.12            Ubuntu-4.15.0-11.12   4.15.5
```

I'm not totally convinced this page is complete or updated on a timely basis but it is the closest answer I've found so far.