# Should I upgrade to the latest Linux Kernel?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I am not asking how to do it, but if it is recommended and what is the concern about it.

I have recently seen that the 4.16 Kernel release was at its end of life and that users were urged to upgrade to 4.17. So I checked my version, and I am currently using the Linux 4.15.0-23-generic Kernel on my up-to-date Ubuntu 18.04...

Is this normal? Why is that this way? Is Ubuntu using an out of date kernel? Should I upgrade manually?

I clarify that there are similar questions, but those I found on this forum did not answer my question at all, so I ask again. I do not consider this a duplicate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please explain how the existing questions do not solve your problem.

Comment: They do not say why ubuntu is using an old kernel, nor what is the concern of upgrading to a new kernel (why should I or shouldn't I upgrade). They just tell how to do it, so I know how and don't ask again.

Comment: Not all kernels are LTS. Like Ubuntu releases  (even year & april = LTS thus outlive the normal releases), the same applies to Linux Kernels.  Ubuntu is not built on short-life kernels. Further Ubuntu LTS releases have their kernels supported for the life of their release. (eg. linux kernel 3.16 will be supported till april 2020 due being classified as an LTS kernel)

Comment: Ubuntu kernels will start with a given Linux kernel number and keep updating long after that original Linux Kernel is End of Life (EOL): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010811/how-do-i-map-linux-kernels-to-ubuntu-kernels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all kernels are LTS.

Like Ubuntu releases (where even.year april release = LTS), their is no formula that applies to Linux Kernels.  You need to watch mailing lists of the kernel devs for their announcements on which are LTS or their supported ranges.

Ubuntu is not built on short-life kernels. Further Ubuntu LTS releases have their kernels supported for the life of their release.

For example,

the linux kernel 4.4 as used in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS reaches its [expected-]EOL in Feb.2022, which is further into the future than Ubuntu 16.04's EOL of April.2021
source: https://www.kernel.org/category/releases.html

Ubuntu LTS releases *generally* use kernels declared [*by upstream LKML*] to be LTS; and any kernel used by Ubuntu will at least be supported as long as its release is (*by upstream or Canonical*). *Kernels don't include the the LTS label as visible as Ubuntu itself does.*

Comment: "*Ubuntu LTS releases use LTS kernels*" is [slightly ambiguous](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932859/why-does-ubuntu-14-04-lts-use-a-non-lts-kernel-version).